# Creating a PCL point cloud using a container of Eigen Vector3d

Tags: eigen, point-cloud-library

I am trying to generate a PCL point cloud. All my points are in the following container type:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d,Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Vector3d> >
```

I would like to create a pointer to a PCL point cloud:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pc
```

What would be the most efficient way to create this point cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since PCL seems to use a float[4] to store the points, when you specify pcl:PointXYZ, you will have to copy each element individually (not tested):

```
pc->points.resize( v.size() );
for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
    pc->points[i].getVector3fMap() = v[i].cast<float>();
```

if you used a vector4d instead and ensured that the last coefficient of each element is 0, you could do a memcpy or even a swap (with a bit of trickery).

Comment: So you mean, if I had   `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f,Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Vector3f> >` instead, could I simply call `pc->points = container` ?

Comment: ah... missed that your original question used a double. You need a cast here (updated answer). And no, using Vector3f still wouldn't have the right memory layout. Vector4f would, but even then you needed some tricks to assign the container directly.

Answer (score 0):

Point Cloud:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

Vector:

```
std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ> > vectorOfPointCloud;
```

Push-back to add point clouds into a vector:

```
vectorOfPointCloud.push_back(*cloud);
```