# Converting Eigen::MatrixXd to pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>

Tags: eigen, point-cloud-library

My question is related to [Creating a PCL point cloud using a container of Eigen Vector3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129018/creating-a-pcl-point-cloud-using-a-container-of-eigen-vector3d) but I am using a `Eigen::MatrixXd` instead of `Eigen::Vector3d`. `getMatrixXfMap()` is not a part of the member function and so cannot be used instead of `getVector3fMap()`. How can the types be converted in this case?

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

// resize to number of points
cloud->points.resize(Pts.rows());

/*DOES NOT WORK */
for(int i=0;i<Pts.rows();i++)
    cloud->points[i].getMatrixXfMap() = Pts[i].cast<float>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be very sexy, but why not just create each point in your for loop? No need for the resize in that case.

```
pcl::PointXYZ temp;
temp.x = Pts[i][0];
temp.y = Pts[i][1];
temp.z = Pts[i][2];
cloud.push_back(temp);
```

Comment: indeed, not sexy at all

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. My `source_cloud` is a Nx3 Matrix constaining XYZ points in float32 format.

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> PointCloudRGBA;

Eigen::MatrixXf convertToPointCloud(const Eigen::MatrixXf source_cloud){
    PointCloudRGBA::Ptr cloud(new PointCloudRGBA);
    cloud->points.resize(source_cloud.rows());
    for(int i=0; i<source_cloud.rows(); i++){
        cloud->points[i].getVector3fMap() = Eigen::Vector3d(source_cloud(i, 0), source_cloud(i, 1), source_cloud(i, 2)).cast<float>();
    }
}
```