# How to initialize point cloud from Eigen MatrixXf in c++

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, point-cloud-library

So I have an input:

```
double* in;
```

I want to make:

```
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud;
```

with the array I have.

The way I figure out is first:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::ColMajor> > M(in,len,chl);
Eigen::MatrixXf Mf = M.cast <float> ();
```

However, I am stuck here. I do not know how to initialize the point cloud with Eigen matrix.

I am thinking if

```
pcl::PointCloud<Eigen::MatrixXf>::Ptr cloud_ar_p(pcl::PointCloud<Eigen::MatrixXf> (Mf));
```

as a first step that would possible work.

Any hint and comments are so much appreciated. I am stuck for a while actually.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129018/creating-a-pcl-point-cloud-using-a-container-of-eigen-vector3d

Comment: @RzuThank you so much. That answer is good!